# Create New Table In SQL Via Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to create (or add) a table in existing Database by EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ObjectContex.ExecuteStoreCommand` (EF4) and execute any SQL command (if you have required permissions in DB). So yes you can create table from "EF". But you will not add this table to mapping.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka : there is no way to add to mapping?

Comment: @Raika: First of all mapping requires new data type for your entity. This can be probably solved by some dynamic code creation (Reflection.Emit), next you need new ObjectSet - it can be solved by some generic factory but you also need new mapping in `MetadataWorkspace` - I have no idea it it is even possible to inject it at runtime. This class itself allows only getting metadata, not setting and `EntityConnection` which produces `MetadataWorkspace` instance also doesn't seem to have any suitable methods. Next you need the code using new type. I would say you should change your architecture.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka : another quetion. EF Control connection itslef. it is possible that 2 EF Class use one database by one Connection?

Comment: @Raika: `EntityConnection` provides constructor which accepts existing db connection and `MetadataWorkspace`. You can then use it for ObjectContext constructor. But I'm not sure if it is good idea to use that connection with two ObjectContext's instances. Why do you need to share that connection?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka : I have some cms application that use EF. i want to make an installer for modules and i have problem with EF. because i can't add my module mapping inside DATA layer. any suggestion? and by saying that i mean have a additional dll for module DATA layer inside my bin folder.

Comment: @Raika: Not sure if this helps. EF offers some possiblity of reusing entities in EDMX. Check this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx So my idea is create your new module with its own EDMX reusing original EDMX. Your module will use its own context and connection but my expectation is that it will be able to work with original entities as well (I didn't try it). Rest of the functionality will work as before.